# What does "given in species" mean in old geometry textbooks?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, geometry, ancient-greece

I recently came across the term "triangle given in species" in Hatton's [*Projective Geometry*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n367/mode/2up?q=species).  Searching in [archive.org](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%22given%20in%20species%22&sin=TXT&page=3) turned up other examples ([such as this](https://archive.org/details/elementsgeometr02leslgoog/page/n380/mode/2up?q=species)) of 19th century texts, and it is also used in Euclid.  But I don't see it defined anywhere.  By context, I think it refers to similar triangles, but it would be nice to see a definition somewhere.  Also, does it have a meaning wider than "similar" in geometry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such terms as “given in species” are defined in Euclid’s *Data* ([Greek](https://books.google.com/books?id=vLM2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q&f=false), [English](https://books.google.com/books?id=LwE_vwEACAAJ&pg=PA367#v=onepage&f=false)):

> III. Rectilineal figures are said to be given in species, which have each of their angles given, and the ratios of their sides given. (English version, R. Simpson, 1810, p. 367)

[*Species* is the translation of *eidos*, shape or form; see LSJ, [εἶδος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ei%29%3Ddos&la=greek#lexicon), def. A.2.b.]

Comment: One speculates that, since everybody had studied Euclid in those days, it was not necessary to define the term -- everybody knew it.  At some time it must have dropped out of usage though.

Comment: Three observations.  Firstly, the phrase plays a different role from "similar": "similar" means having the same angles and aspect ratios as some other shape; "given in species" means having prescribed angles and aspect ratios, no other shape required.  Secondly, Google Scholar and Google Books reveal it's _extremely_ rare for any work to use both phrases, "given in species" and "similar triangle".  Thirdly, Thomas Heath, in his translation of _Elements_, claimed Proclus was confused about the meaning of "given in species": could this have contributed to the phrase dropping out of usage?

Comment: @DanielHatton Thanks for the observations. I think I would say "no other shape *given*," but that's probably just quibbling. Another way to say it is that "similar" is a relation between two triangles and "given in species" is a property or assumption about a single triangle. Google Ngrams, for what its data is worth, show that "given in species" had a precipitous decline in usage around 1840. I don't know why.  I suspect education reform.

Comment: I wonder if this is the same root as the word "specific" in the sense of "specific heat", "specific gravity", "specific strength", *etc.* to mean a ratio of two quantities.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Certainly "specific" and "species" have the same root in Latin, but I guess the question is whether scientists adopted the scientific terms based on the mathematical meaning of "given in species."

Answer (score 1):

This terminology does appear in English 100+ years ago, and is arguably archaic, but just means "types" or "kinds".